# Using explode twice and then compairing username to textfile php

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble and I hope that you can help me. I have an assignment in school where you're supposed to create a login form where you can both login and register. The username and password is saved to a textfile (I know you're supposed to use a database but the assignment requires textfile). In the textfile the username and hashed password are saved like this:

```
lilly;$2y$10$wZIMr0G4efgOR0vYxlX0deBSqS8KPDqjM4DseMctvIwO43pbuY.MW
kajsa;$2y$10$m2WfOQvPkc3rqEVoAQUCZeb.uTHYMRMtnnimamxGE3..cAFrhCdNa
admin;$2y$10$qrnU4R9/r3lGUw3o/3IhT.0yoZLNUQYXsNVD.3iINvICVa58mXRYm
helga;$2y$10$uUxW/QPkPREWfcX6C2Tdhu35KHZi5vhP5ShD.wVmZSEDuz7ZxS6j6
```

According to the instructions of the assigment this is how they are supposed to be saved. The problem I'm having is that I need to explode the file twice, once at the linebreak and once at every `;` sign. I looked around and found a way to use explode twice by placing the second explode in a `foreach..as` loop but I'm not sure it's working and when I use `printr` on the `foreach ($userlogin as $username){` the array comes out empty. Am I using explode correctly and if I am then why is the array empty? If I'm not using explode correctly then how am I supposed to use it instead?

Here's the code:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $anvandare = $_POST['anvandare']; //username
    $losen = $_POST['losen']; //pasword

    $hashlosen = password_hash($losen,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if (empty($anvandare))
    {
        echo "Vänligen mata in användarnamn!<br>";//Enter username
    }
    if (empty($losen))
    {
        echo "Vänligen mata in lösenord!<br>"; //enter password.
    }

    if (!empty($anvandare) && !empty($losen)) //if both fields are filled in, do the following:
    {
        $openlogg1 = fopen('userlog.txt', 'a+'); //Open userlog.txt for reading and writing.
        $path1 = 'userlog.txt';

        if (file_exists($path1)) 
        {
            $userdatafile = file_get_contents($path1); //Turn file into string.
            $userdata = explode(PHP_EOL, $userdatafile);//explode file into array.

            foreach ($userdata as $userlogin){
                $userlogin = explode(';', $userlogin); //explode second time.
            }

            foreach ($userlogin as $username){//Looping through second array.
            }
            print_r($username); //print array.
                if ($username==$anvandare){ //if $username equals $anvandare echo username is occupied.
                    echo "Användarnamnet är upptaget, välj ett annat.";
                }
                else { //if they are not egual to each other write username and hashed password to userlog.txt.
                    fwrite($openlogg1, $anvandare .";".$hashlosen . PHP_EOL);
                }
            }
            fclose($openlogg1);
        }
    }
```

I'm new to this so go easy on me. If you find any other errors than the ones I'm talking about let me know!

Thank you!

Comment: To debug your code, read on var_dump();  This will show you the contents of your arrays as you build them.  Then check this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php, which will read a file directly into an array.  One explode can be taken out using this!

Comment: First: foreach ($userlogin as $username){//Looping through second array. } You are closing your foreach right after you opened it? Remove that }.  By the time you `print_r($username);`, $username does not exist anymore.  Balance your `{ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using explode correctly, but you're not processing the result correctly.

```
foreach ($userdata as $userlogin){
    $userlogin = explode(';', $userlogin); //explode second time.
}
```

This overwrites the `$userlogin` value on each loop.

Change the code to

```
foreach ($userdata as $userlogin) {
    $userlogin = explode(';', $userlogin); //explode second time.
    foreach ($userlogin as $username) {//Looping through second array.
        print_r($username); //print array.
    }
}
```

And you should see something more sensible.